# Is this question too localized?

Tags: discussion

This [question](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/8968/why-is-triclopyr-not-available-in-california) only relates to buying an herbicide in California.  Rather than flagging it I thought I would find out the opinions of others.

Leaving aside the issue of only being valid in California whether a product is available or not is a very transitory issue that can change from year to year.

So, what are others opinions on this question and others that may be similar in the future?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things.

1. Too localized as a close reason is no more. That doesn't mean the sentiment is gone, but it does mean there isn't an *easy* reason why close these.
2. California as a state would be far from too localized. California is a big state and there are plenty of gardeners and others in the state to whom this would likely be relevant information.

the original sentiment of too localized was that that information would only be relevant to a *very* small group of people (likely only the OP). In this case it's relevant to anyone who lives in California.

Granted, this particular question might be tough to answer, though if it's a state regulation issue, then it's probably pretty easy to find. If it's a supply issue it might be harder to iron out. Other reasons might be even harder. However, I don't think it's a question that deserves closure on the grounds of the now deprecated Too Localized.